# Bound observable collection not showing in list view

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

If I use `items` as `ItemsSource` it is working, yet if I use the `sorted_items` it does not show in the list view.

```
ObservableCollection<myModel> items = new  ObservableCollection<myModel>();
ObservableCollection<myModel> sorted_items = new  ObservableCollection<myModel>();

lv_items.ItemsSource = sorted_items;

items.Add(new myModel
{
    ImageSource = myImage,
    Name = item_name;
});

sorted_items = items;

for (int j = 0; j < sorted_items.Count; j++)     
{                                                   
    sorted_items.Move(sorted_items.Count - 1, j)
}
```

Comment: This code will not even compile because you are using `sorted_items` before you declare it.

Comment: My bad, I wrote it in scratch. Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *Spidey* senses tells me you should try moving `lv_items.ItemsSource = sorted_items` after your assignment, or even better after your `for`

```
for (int j = 0; j < sorted_items.Count; j++)     
{                                                   
   sorted_items.Move(sorted_items.Count - 1, j)
}

lv_items.ItemsSource = sorted_items;
```

Comment: @BrianSanchez make sure you mark it as answered if it suits your purpose :)